# Upgrade from httpd 2.4.6 to 2.4.41

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

I am new to Linux and currently need to upgrade the httpd on RHEL7 from 2.4.6 to 2.4.41, to fix CVE-2018-1312. Can someone help me with the command to do this? Do I also need to take any backups before I upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

[CVE-2018-1312](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2018-1312) was fixed in version 2.4.6-89 of the RHEL 7 `httpd` package; see [RHSA-2019:1898](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2019:1898) for details.

You don’t need to upgrade to 2.4.41 for this; if your system is kept up-to-date, it will already have the fix, otherwise upgrade as usual to get it (see [How do I apply package updates to my RHEL system?](https://access.redhat.com/articles/11258)).

The upgrade is safe, you don’t need to take any *additional* backups (beyond those which should already be in place to protect your data).

Comment: Hello Stephen, Thanks for the answer. My httpd is already on 2.4.6-90.el7. Our network has strictly suggested to update to 2.4.41

Comment: That means “your network” doesn’t understand RHEL updates then, unfortunately. In distributions such as RHEL, Debian etc., bugs are fixed by backporting the relevant fix, not by upgrading to the latest version of a given piece of software. Your system is already protected from CVE-2018-1312. If you try to manually upgrade to 2.4.41 you will be giving up the support you get with your RHEL distribution.